# Is there any high-performance (no web-based) multi-platform advanced code editor?

Tags: open-source, source-code

I think most of us have used any advanced code editor sometime, namely Atom, Sublime Text, VS Code, Brackets, ...

I personally love Atom, I have already mastered it and with that I have been dealing with its weak points: performance with big files is the biggest one IMO.

Browsing and researching I have found that most advanced code editors (named in the first paragraph) are web-based, programmed in HTML, CSS and JavaScript (or variants of this one, which are almost the same).

Several people recommended me to take the step and move to EMACS or VIM. I really have no that amount of time to start learning these, and I am not really interested.

So the question is the title: Is there any advanced code editor that is programmed in a higher performance language (C++, Rust, ...), available for Windows, Linux or Mac with almost the same good features as the mentioned ones (open-source would be great)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not have a recommendation for you but maybe you can try timecop: https://atom.io/packages/timecop
With this plugin you see where time is spent while Atom loads. This could help to identify slow packages.

Comment: Sublime is written in C++ and Python.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Do not know, but Sublime is not free nor open source, is really buggy, and somehow not as fast as it should be opening large files.

Comment: @Davdriver Fair enough, just pointing out that it was written in C++ and Python is all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Sublime Text, try [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/), it has some similar menuitems, and loading speed for huge files (100-800Mb) is faster than in ST. But rendering speed is slower than in ST.

It also has Python plugins for developers.

Comment: Seems promising, will check it out...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe what you are looking for could be in the below:

1. Eclipse
2. IntelliJ IDEA

Great IDEs and very powerful. Eclipse in particular as it has tons of extensions to further focus on your line of development.

Hope this helped.

Links:
http://www.eclipse.org/
https://www.jetbrains.com/

Comment: The problem with IDEA and Eclipse is that both are resource-heavy, and I am looking for just an advanced code editor, not a full programming IDE.
But thanks for your contribution anyway.

Comment: I understand. Would it have to be cross-platform? As an example, Coda is a great editor for the Mac. Notepad++ is great for Windows. Lime Text is based on Go but is crossplatform. Wouldnt know if it handles large files though.

Comment: I love Notepad++, and there is no money for Mac stuff. But will check out Lime Text, seems promising.

Comment: Lime Text is a try to make Sublime Text clone on Go. It is not done.